# Symfony2 customize form error messages

Tags: forms, symfony, customization, message

can you please help me understand how to customize error messages in a form with Symfony2?
I want to change the HTML layout, adding div, class, etc...

Reading the guide, it gives a piece of code to put in a file called `fields_errors.html.twig` but it doesn't tells where to put this file and if some extra configuration is needed.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you want to modify the error message beeing shown, or change markup/rendering of the message?

Comment: I want to change the rendering, the HTML tags, classes, etc..

Answer (score 5):

You have to put the template in `Resourses/views/` folder of your bundle. For example,

```
{# Vendor/YourBundle/Resourses/views/form_fields.html.twig #}

{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_errors %}
    {# your form error template #}
{% endblock form_errors %}

{# other customized blocks #}
```

And then in your form page template,

```
{% extends your:page:layout %}

{% form_theme form  'VendorYourBundle::form_fields.html.twig' %}

 {{ form_errors(form.field) }}
 {# ..... #}
```

For more option and implementation reference check [form theme cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-theming-methods) and [default field layout implementation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L271)

Answer (score 1):

You can customise all your error messages at once in your template:

```
<div class="your_new_class">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
```

Or individually (if your field is **title** for example)

```
<div class="your_new_class">
    {{ form_errors(form.task) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In symfony3 first call de theme form in config.yml

```
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
form_themes: 
    - 'YourBundle:FormTheme:error.html.twig'
```

Twig error.html.twig example

```
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {% for error in errors %}
     <strong>{{ error.message }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```