# Symfony Customize form errors css

Tags: php, html, symfony, validation, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8. In registration form, when I submit form with empty fields, it is showing validation errors in

tag. It is really making the UI looks bad. How can I change the css of each validation error messages.

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register','novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.email) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.username) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second) }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering form fields using `form_row` widget which renders label, field & related error to do custom styling you can render your fields and their labels and errors individually like

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register','novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}

    {{ form_label(form.email) }}

    <div class="some_class">{{ form_errors(form.email) }} </div>

    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}

<style type="text/css">

.some_class{
 /* write custom styling rules here */
}

</style>
```

Or get all errors in one place like

```
{# render any "global" errors #}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

[Reference: Twig Template Form Function and Variable Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

The errors have their own element and classes that you could target from your css.

One basic approach could by using a form theme as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes), or you could [create your own form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig).

If you want to customise the tags it renders you could do what this guy does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121180/symfony2-customize-form-error-messages).